# Not able to see the java files in the sonar web page

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

Hi i am able to integrate the project with the sonar 5.0 i.e, Started the Sonar server and associated the project with help of the sonar-runner 2.4. i am able to see the project in sonar web console but when i click on the project -> major issue-> Rule -> and the java class. it is not opening the java class to the show the issue in the java class.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me - SQ version 5.0.1. I m able to see the source code along with issues/coverage numbers of a particular class. Double check if you are clicking on the actual '.java' class name.